# How to track the current execution of my applications in Apache Spark

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have an **Apache Spark service instance on IBM cloud**(light plan). After I submit a Spark job I want to see its progress, it would be perfect to see it the Spark way - get the Spark progress UI with number of partitions and everything. I would also like to get a connection to the history server.

I saw that I can run `./spark-submit.sh ... --status <app id>` but I would like to get something more informative.

I saw the comment

> You can track the current execution of your running application and see the details of previously run jobs on the Spark job history UI by clicking Job History on the Analytics for Apache Spark service console.

[here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/using_spark-submit.html#running-a-spark-application-using-the-spark-submit-sh-script), but fail to understand where exactly I get this console/history thing.

As a side note, is there any detailed technical documentation of this service, e.g. number of concurrent jobs which can run, technology stack etc..?

Answer (score 0):

As per spark Documentation:

Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040, that displays useful information about the application. This includes:

A list of scheduler stages and tasks
A summary of RDD sizes and memory usage
Environmental information.
Information about the running executors
You can access this interface by simply opening **[http://{driver-node}:4040](http://%7Bdriver-node%7D:4040)** in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

Bottom Line : http://{driver-node}:4040 (replace driver-node with the node where spark job invoked) and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am sorry I didn't mention it specifically in the question (only in the tags), I am asking it from the context of "Apache Spark" service on IBM cloud. It has a different management, configuration, etc.. and the IP of the driver node it not known to the user

Comment: As per IBM Cloud Documentation: `https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine/spark-history.html#viewing-spark-history`

Comment: @Anton.P was the url and info helpful?